# auto-int floats when writing into an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[-2,  1, -4, -9], [ 1, -3, -2,  3]])

print(A[1] - A[0] * A[1, 0] / A[0, 0])

A[1] = A[1] - A[0] * A[1, 0] / A[0, 0]
print(A[1])
```

it returns:

```
A
>>> array([[-2,  1, -4, -9],
       [ 1, -3, -2,  3]])

print(A[1] - A[0] * A[1, 0] / A[0, 0])
>>> [ 0.  -2.5 -4.  -1.5]

A[1] = A[1] - A[0] * A[1, 0] / A[0, 0]
print(A[1])
>>> [ 0 -2 -4 -1]
```

Why do these outputs different? It seems numpy automatically turn floats to intergers when writing into an array

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. You have an integer array, so whatever value you try to assign to one of each elements, it will be cast to an integer. The first print shows a float array because the arithmetic computations create a new array. But when you try to assign said values back to the original array, that -2.5 will become -2.

Comment: Is there some solutions to auto-create a float array except for `dtype = float`?

Comment: `np.array` tries to be smart and figure out the smallest type that can accommodate all the data. If you have a list of lists full of integers, it will be an integer array by default. If at least one of them is float (or complex), the respective type will be used instead. Nothing wrong with using `dtype=float` to be explicit, or to be sure you'll have the right type regardless of input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Reti43, I should add `dtype = float` like:

`A=np.array([[-2,  1, -4, -9], [ 1, -3, -2,  3]], dtype = float)`